# wxMediaCtrl error

Tags: wxwidgets

i want to use wxMediaCtrl for this i make a header file with content like

```
#ifndef MEDIA_H_
#define MEDIA_H_
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/mediactrl.h>
class media: public wxFrame

{

public:

 wxWindow *window;

     media(const wxString& title);

     wxMediaCtrl *media_ctrl;

};


#endif /* MEDIA_H_ */
```

and make a cpp file with code like

```
#include "media.h"

media::media(const wxString& title)

      :wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(600, 600))

{

    window=new wxWindow(this,wxID_ANY,wxPoint(0,0),wxSize(600,600),wxBORDER_SIMPLE,wxT("window"));
    media_ctrl= new wxMediaCtrl(window, wxID_ANY , wxT(""),wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxT(""), wxDefaultValidator, wxT("hello"));}
```

when i m trying to run the page ,i got an error like

```
make all 
Building target: media
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ `wx-config --libs` -o"media"  ./programfiles/main.o ./programfiles/media.o   
./programfiles/media.o: In function `wxMediaCtrl::wxMediaCtrl(wxWindow*, int, wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxString const&, wxValidator const&, wxString const&)':
media.cpp:(.text._ZN11wxMediaCtrlC1EP8wxWindowiRK8wxStringRK7wxPointRK6wxSizelS4_RK11wxValidatorS4_[wxMediaCtrl::wxMediaCtrl(wxWindow*, int, wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxString const&, wxValidator const&, wxString const&)]+0x35): ****undefined reference to `vtable for wxMediaCtrl'****
media.cpp:(.text._ZN11wxMediaCtrlC1EP8wxWindowiRK8wxStringRK7wxPointRK6wxSizelS4_RK11wxValidatorS4_[wxMediaCtrl::wxMediaCtrl(wxWindow*, int, wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxString const&, wxValidator const&, wxString const&)]+0x9a): undefined reference to `wxMediaCtrl::Create(wxWindow*, int, wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxString const&, wxValidator const&, wxString const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [media] Error 1
```

can anyone tell me where i m doing the mistake

Comment: Please fix the formatting of this question.  It is incomprehensible!

Comment: Thanks for reformatting - now I can see what the question is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using

`wx-config --libs std,media`

in building...

Answer (score 0):

To build wxWidgets with wxMediaCtrl enabled on linux (gstreamer 0.10) libgconf2-dev and libgstreamer0.10-dev are required.

http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxMediaCtrl